# Vim: Replace all dots but the last one in a line

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a way to replace all dots in a line except the last one.

Example:

`Blah - whatever - foo.bar.baz.avi` should become
`Blah - whatever - foo bar bar.avi`

Since I'll have more than one line in the file and the amount of dots varies in each line I'm looking for a generic solution and not something like "Replace the first X matches" with X being a constant.

Comment: Yes, I want to replace all dots with spaces except the one between the filename and the extension.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
%s/\.\(.*\.\)\@=/ /g
```

`\@=` is a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It only matches a full stop if there are any following full stops.

See `:help zero-width`.

Comment: Oh my, the vim syntax for lookaheads etc. is ugly. I wonder why they didn't use the syntax PCRE etc. use

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Yeah... I was very confused by the fact that the pattern has to precede the lookahead "operator"... but nevertheless, they are very handy :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster try `:perldo s/searchme/replaceme/g` of Perl5 regexen? Also: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Perl_compatible_regular_expressions

Answer (score 7):

As a variation on the first answer you may prefer this syntax:

```
%s/\.\ze.*\./ /g
```

It let's you put the assertion that there be a following full stop after the search operator.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that might be useful to learn (replace inside visual selection) would be:
 `:g/^/normal $F.hv0:s/\%V\./ /g`**`^M`**
where `^M` is entered with <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This means: for each line (`g/^/`) type `$F.`(go to last dot), visually select from character to the left till beginning of line (`hv0`), and then replace dots (`:s/\./ /g^M`) only inside visual selection (`\%V`).